# Django fail to raise an error when a minimum length password is required

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an form that allows a user to create a user account. I also enforce a minimum password length of 8 and when that is breached , An error would be raise . The problem is , it doesn't raise an error whenever the minimum password length of 8 is breached .

Can someone kindly help me.

```
def Registration(request):  
    form = UserRegistration()
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserRegistration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
                email=form.cleaned_data['email'], 
                password=form.cleaned_data['password']
                )
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
             return render(request,'choose.html',{'form':form})

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form},)
```

my forms.py

```
 class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'required':'Error Missing Field , Please Fill this Field'})

    password = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
    )

    MIN_LENGTH = 8

    def clean_password(self):
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']

            if len(password) > self.MIN_LENGTH:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("The new password must be at least %d characters long." % self.MIN_LENGTH)

            return password
```

My template

```
<form method ="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}


<span id="error">{{form.username.errors}}</span>
<span id="error2">{{form.email.errors}}</span>
<span id="error3">{{form.password.errors}}</span>

{{form.username}}
{{form.email}}
{{form.password}}
    <input type = "submit" value= "save" id="box2"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is not correct:

Instead of

```
if len(password) > self.MIN_LENGTH:
```

use

```
if len(password) <= self.MIN_LENGTH:
                #<---- changed condition
```

Answer (score 3):

`clean_new_password1` will never be called as `new_password1` is not a model field, change it to `clean_password`, or call super to override any default checking

Comment: And use < in the password length test